# c# Process exe with arguments gives error

Tags: c#, cmd, process, arguments, exe

I sort of stuck into what should be a small issue. I need to run two different processes but the second failures.

My first process is:

```
        string workingDirectory = "c:\\xxxx\\bin\\";
        string fileName = "xxxx.xxxx.cmd";
        string arguments = "-Sxxxx -f -d --port xxxx > c:\\xxxx\\tmp\\bug.log 2>&1";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        startInfo.FileName = fileName;
        startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();
```

No worries here. Everything works but the second.

```
        string workingDirectory = "c:\\xxxx\\bin\\";
        string fileName = "WebDaemon.exe";
        string arguments = "-debug -i WebDaemon.xxxx.1234 --ServerPort=4444 --MultipleServerPorts=1 --CGIPort=4500 --CGICallbackPort=4600 --MinServerProcs=2 --MaxServerProcs=2 > c:\\xxxx\\tmp\\WebDaemonTrace.log 2>&1";

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory;
        startInfo.FileName = fileName;
        startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = startInfo;
        process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        process.Start();
```

Gives an error. The process created and shows up in taskmanager, but after 5 seconds it disappears. Furthermore i can read in a debug message that:
"commandline argument '>' is unknown"

I cannot seem to find the problem. Open to any suggestions :-)

Comment: Redirection is handled by CMD.EXE. So `cmd /c webdaemon.exe`.

Comment: So "cmd /c webdaemon.exe" becomes your fileName?

Comment: `cmd` as in `cmd.exe` is your filename. Arguments are `/c webdaemon -debug -i WebDaemon.xxxx.1234 --ServerPort=4444 --MultipleServerPorts=1 --CGIPort=4500 --CGICallbackPort=4600 --MinServerProcs=2 --MaxServerProcs=2 > c:\\xxxx\\tmp\\WebDaemonTrace.log 2>&1`. Perhaps `>>` which appends is better.

Comment: Wow. You saved the day. Can you pæease elaborate a bit on redirection.